# Using GCP Assets API with Python, I'm stuck with "400 No supported asset type matches" error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I spend a whole afternoon trying to make it works, but I'm still stuck...
I'm trying to get all compute instances in a `GCP` project with a Python (3.8.10) program.

Here is the code :

```
from google.cloud import asset_v1

def sample_search_all_resources(scope_value):
    # Create a client
    client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = asset_v1.SearchAllResourcesRequest(
        scope=scope_value,
        read_mask="displayName,assetType",
        asset_types="compute.*",
    )

    # Make the request
    page_result = client.search_all_resources(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    for response in page_result:
        print(response)

sample_search_all_resources("projects/<project_id>")
```

I tried all examples from the documentation, but I still get

`"google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 No supported asset type matches: c. See https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types for supported searchable asset types.".`

I tried with a Rest Client (Insomnia) and "compute.*" worked.

Without the asset_types condition, the program works well.

Any clue will be welcome!

Comment: When referencing an SDK or examples, I recommend including links to them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you posted, it seems that the asset_types parameter is not being interpreted correctly.

So I agree with Mr John Hanley's comment. Instead of using "compute.*" on the asset_types parameter, you can try using a specific asset type for Compute Engine instances, such as `compute.googleapis.com/Instance`. This may help in narrowing down the search and avoiding the error.

Try also leaving the asset_types empty and if it searches all the searchable asset types with no error, then "compute.*" is an invalid asset type.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this also on two separate attempts a few months apart until I remembered how to solve it.  You have to format the asset_types argument as an ARRAY of strings--even if you only want to pass it a single value.  Enclose the string in [ ] and it will work. eg. `asset_types=["compute.googleapis.com/Instance"],`

Comment: Yes, asset_types is a list of strings: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/searchAllResources

Comment: That's true JH.  But unfortunately, the error message when you pass a single valid string without encapsulating it in an array is misleading.  The type in the API reference should probably use the word array, or include this detail, or the API response could be more clear when it receives something other than an array.  Best case, it would just be more flexible and accept the single string value.  I bet that is more commonly requested than multiple values or patterns, but I don't have any data to say for sure.